# Creating/Using compound indexes IndexedDB

Tags: angular, indexeddb

I am trying to implement `IndexedDB` in my angular app and I am having a problem trying to create and use compound indexes.

I have a few indexes that I want.

```
const objectStore: IDBObjectStore = this._Database.createObjectStore('data', {autoIncrement: true});
objectStore.createIndex('duplicate', ['sId', 'type', 'cancel']);
objectStore.createIndex('id', ['id']);
```

When I add data to the database and look in Chrome DevTools I see that there is data in the object store but none of the indexes.

The `duplicate` index I am trying to use for checking if something already exists. The SQL query for what I am trying to accomplish would look like this.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE sID = {someValue} AND type = {someValue} AND cancel = {someValue}
```

When I try to make the request it looks like this

```
const request: IDBRequest = objectStore.index('duplicate').count(IDBKeyRange.only([data.sId, data.type, 0]));
```

but the count always comes back with nothing even thought I can see it has been saved to the store.

I can get indexes to work if I do single keyPaths like

```
objectStore.createIndex('id', ['id']);
```

but keypaths that have multiple keys dont work

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: 1) Can you clarify what you mean by "count always comes back with nothing"? 2) Are you sure the parameters to your count are the same variable types (e.g. string vs number) as the values in the object store?

Comment: @Josh 1. meaning I would expect the `objectStore.index('duplicate').count` request to return a number if stuff were in that index (there should be). 2. Looking at it again the `0` parameter does not match the data type of the object (its a boolean) but even with that changed when I look at the database in the Chrome DevTools under `Application` there is nothing in the index

Comment: still confused. 1) what is the return type of count? it should be 0 or some larger integer. are you seeing anything else like undefined? 2) you cannot index a boolean, not sure how you managed to create such an index, you should have received an error when calling createIndex

Comment: @Josh what is returned is a number (in this case 0 because the index is empty). 2. Ahh ha! I was not aware of this, When I take the boolean value out of the index I get things in the index. So would the only way to check the boolean now is to loop through everything and check the boolean value?

Comment: store 1 for true, 0 for false. or, store something like 1 or a string value for true, and no property at all for false.

Comment: also not sure what i was thinking in earlier comment, you will not get an error when calling createIndex, it just wont work because you cannot index booleans